Transactions proposed from a Safe account configured with threshold equal to 2, are being set as if just one confirmation is required
I had previously proposed and executed  succesfully transactions with this safe.At the beginning, the safe was configured with a threshold of 2. Then, 2 owners were removed, leaving it with a threshold of 1, and it was working fine. Later, the owners were added back, and the threshold was modified to 2 again, but since this last configuration, every proposed transaction appears as if it only requires 1 signature. I already checked through the apikit that the new threshold is 2. (apiKit.getSafeInfo(safeAddress)).  How can I make my safe proposes transactions with te right confirmations requirements?

Thanks a lot for your good question.
I need a little bit more context to post a helpful reply.

Does your question relate to Safe Wallet?
Do the transactions only appear to require one signature, but still require two signatures?
What is the required threshold being displayed?

With more information, I hope to provide an answer to you.
